# Cannot create new connection or login to added user?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to Oracle Express 11g and create a new user. I keep on getting the same error when I try to create a new connection (and test it) or when I try to login with a newly created username and password (mad by right-clicking "other users" table in default connection "xe")

The error-

> Failure - Test Failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Try logging in with the user you have problem with logging into sql developer in sql*plus and let uw know if you are able to login in sql*plus.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you're using an user with not enough privilegies, try with "system" user.
That should solve your problem.

Verify the priviligies of the user you created.

Comment: Do you mean 'sys' user ? I can login with username 'sys'. But I still cannot create use a newly created user or create a new connection.

Comment: Take a look on this page: https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2386352, this probably could be related to a bad log in in fact.